# Is there a theoretical maximum number of sides a single die can have? If so what is it?

Tags: geometry, dice, polyhedra

> Is there a theoretical maximum number of sides a single die can have? If so, what is it?

The question is fairly self-explanatory.  I read the Nerdist article ["This d120 is the Largest Mathematically Fair Die Possible"](https://nerdist.com/this-d120-is-the-largest-mathematically-fair-die-possible) about the die shown below, but it didn't really answer my question, and it seems to just talk about a *physical* limit (which I'm sure exists - is there an answer to this too?).

[image]

Any thoughts/comments?

Comment: Here's a numberphile video on this question. In the comments there is a link to a paper written about the topic if you are interested. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7zT9MljJ3Y&t=325s

Comment: The article essentially acknowledges the fact that there is no *theoretical* maximum: *"[...] before you yell at me about a cylinder or a double pyramid [...]"*.

Comment: I suppose the point of it is that all $120$ sides are congruent and surrounded by the same types of vertices—it starts with a dodecahedron, divides each pentagon into $5$ isosceles triangles then subdivides those along their axis of symmetry. But are identical faces the only way to guarantee fairness?

Comment: FYI, the dice in the figure are [hexakis icosahedra, aka disdyakis triacontahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disdyakis_triacontahedron). Ed Pegg's MathPuzzle.com has a ["Fair Dice" entry](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/Fairdice.htm) that lists all possible "isohedra" (polyhedra with equivalent faces). Pegg briefly muses about whether non-isohedral dice exist, considering that there's a "right height" a which a polyhedron with a square base and isosceles-triangular lateral faces becomes fair, but he suspects that the fairness may be dependent upon conditions including "throwing method".

Comment: @Blue I already have trouble seeing how one of these can be thrown randomly—you've got to somehow give it a randomly chosen axis of rotation, or encourage it to roll around in random directions.

Answer (score 1):

The number of sides of dices surely is unbounded. Just take any regular $n$-gon and errect a symmetrical dipyramid on that polygon, then serving for its equatorial pseudo facet. That dice then obviously will have $2n$ faces.

--- rk